# Tagging referral to avoid edit war (re specific instance of application of 'esta')

Tags: discussion, tagging

The Tile of [When crossing US border, does original date limit still apply if no further date limit is written in passport? [duplicate]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88729/when-crossing-us-border-does-original-date-limit-still-apply-if-no-further-date) was originally "ESTA expiration date?". However the question has nothing to do with the date of expiration of any ESTA.

The [esta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esta) tag was one of those chosen by OP when first posting. I removed it while editing the post. A user has specifically reinstated it (that is, the only change for that edit).

Do you think it appropriate to tag the Q as it stands with [esta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esta)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is about the US Visa Waiver Program, not ESTA. While the two are often confused, [esta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esta) should be used only for questions specifically about the ESTA requirement, application, etc..., not anything to do with a visit one might make under the Visa Waiver Program while holding an ESTA. I would not tag this question with [esta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esta)

It is, however, rather understandable that a user might have added the tag back, since the original title of the question was, incorrectly, about ESTA expiration dates, and it certainly looks incorrect to remove [esta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esta) from a question that, based on the title, clearly seemed to be about that topic.